# replace '.' with '' in ternary operator

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check the string starts with '.' eg .net and replace it as net using ternary operator in javascript.I want to replace the below code with ternary operator

```
arr = ".net"
var val = arr.startsWith('.');

if(val == true)
{
    arr = arr.replace('.','');
} 
else
{
    arr;
}
```

tried as
`arr = arr.startsWith('.') ? arr.replace('.','') : arr;`

Comment: Try `str.replace(/^\./, '')`. No need to use a ternary operator

Comment: Why do you need ternary? You can simply write `if(val){arr = "arr.replace('.','');}`. There is no need for the else part and the `== true` check as well

Comment: `if (arr.indexOf(".")===0) arr = arr.substring(1)` or `arr = arr.startsWith(".")?arr.substring(1):arr;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var arr = '.net'
arr = arr.startsWith('.')
  ? arr.slice(1)
  : arr
```

You probably don't want to replace the `.` as there could be a `.` elsewhere in the string. `.slice` will just remove the first character and return the rest.

Answer (score 5):

You can use regex for that.

**Idea:**

- Create a pattern which checks for string that starts with `.`
- Use it to replace to blank string.
- If a string does not start with `.`, it will not replace.

```js
function replace(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\./, '')
}

console.log(replace('.net'))
console.log(replace('asp.net'))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly but is a much more elegant solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDot(arr) {
  return arr.startsWith('.') ? arr.slice(1) : arr;
}
```

You can add a function like `removeDot`, invoke it with whatever string you want and get the output without dot.